# Is it possible to return a specific index element from a hasmany relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many

```
$row->sub_category[0]->name
```

when i checked other questions, i could see that there is option to access the first and last elements, but is there a way to access an element based in array index value.

I need to get the n-th item in a hasmany relationship (where you know n)  and would getting it on its own direactly without foreach loop (without loading other relationship elements ).

Comment: If it's by array index value you want then you can do `sub_category[$index]` . It's not clear exactly what you need here. Do you need to get the *n*-th item in a hasmany relationship (where you know n) or do you need to get the first item that fulfils some condition and do you need to do this after you've gotten all relationship items or would getting it on its own without loading other relationship elements work for you?

Comment: I need to get the n-th item in a hasmany relationship (where you know n)  and would getting it on its own direactly without foreach loop (without loading other relationship elements ). I have updated in question also. Thanks

Comment: does ->offsetGet($nth) solve your problem?

Comment: $row->sub_category->offsetGet(2)->name , is giving me an error, undefined offset, for all n values

Comment: @RoshJ have you dumped $row->sub_category ? if it doen't have a 3th value, it will throw that error

Comment: yes, dumped, its fine

Comment: can you add the dump?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the N-th item of a relationship without loading all other elements you  can (probably) use query:

```
$nthSubcategory = $row->sub_category()->skip($n-1)->first()
```

If it doesn't exist then `$nthSubcategory` will end up being null